# estoy tratando de guardar datos en una db pero no se guardan en ella, es un bot de economia en discord

Tags: javascript, bot

```
const Discord = require ('discord.js');
const megadb = require ("megadb");
let eco= new megadb.crearDB("economia");

module.exports = {
    name: "work",
    alias: ["w"],

    async execute(client, message, args){

        let server = message.guild.id
        let user = message.author.id
        let usuario = message.author.tag

        if(!eco.tiene(`${server}_${user}`)){
            eco.establecer(`${server}_${user}`, {"efectivo": 0, "banco": 0})
        }
            

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 180)
    console.log("se ha agregado  " + random + " a la billetera de " + user)

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

    .setAuthor({name: "Trabajaste"})
    .setDescription( usuario + " Ha trabajado y ha ganado " + random + "")
    .setColor ("GREEN")

    await eco.sumar(`${server}_${user}_efectivo`, random)

    message.channel.send(`{ embeds: [embed] }`);
} }
```

codigo

se ha agregado  179 a la billetera de 600405239065084001
(node:12876) DeprecationWarning: Passing strings for MessageEmbed#setAuthor is deprecated. Pass a sole object instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\megadb\methods\sumar.js:15
if(!object_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) return Promise.reject(new errorDB(`No se encontro la propiedad ${key}, base de datos: ${self.database_name}`, 'PROPIEDAD NO EXISTENTE', 'sumar', clave, number))
^

MEGADB [ERROR]: No se encontro la propiedad 696380553515106380_600405239065084001_efectivo, base de datos: economa
at sumar (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\megadb\methods\sumar.js:15:63)
at crearDB.sumar (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\megadb\class\crearDB.js:142:11)
at Object.execute (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\comandos\work.js:29:15)
at Client. (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\index.js:39:9)
at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:26:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:346:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:478:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:317:10) {
type: 'PROPIEDAD NO EXISTENTE',
method: 'sumar',
param1: '696380553515106380_600405239065084001_efectivo',
param2: 179,
reference: '.sumar("696380553515106380_600405239065084001_efectivo", 179)'

error

//Se que falla, pero no como arreglarlo

Comment: Pues el cómo arreglarlo es fácil... crea el objeto antes de intentar sumarle nada.

Comment: Y como podria crear un objeto de esa manera, es la ID de un discord user, no se muy bien como

Comment: El problema es que estás creando el objeto como `\`${server}_${user}\`, {"efectivo": 0, "banco": 0}`, pero luego intentas acceder a él como `\`${server}_${user}_efectivo`\`, claramente no son lo mismo, no? Imagino que lo correcto sería algo así: `eco.sumar(\`${server}_${user}.efectivo\`, random)`

Comment: Muchas gracias lo consegui solucionar todo excepto algo que sale ahora, me pone que user no fue definido

Comment: Esta solucionado todo excepto que ahora tengo este error, ya no teniendo que pasa.PS C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord> node index.js
 se ha agregado 171 a la cuenta de 600405239065084001
C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);

Comment: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)      
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)    
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\Casa\Desktop\botdiscord\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:176:15)

Comment: method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/989465935389814857/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}